# Creating a database and collection programmatically for Azure Cosmos DB via Mongo DB .NET Driver

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using the .NET MongoDb driver and Azure Cosmos DB Emulator. I am trying to create a database and collection on startup of a dotnet core Web Api project.

I am running the following code within the `ConfigureServices` function in `Startup.cs`.

```
var connectionString = databaseConfig.GetValue<string>("connectionString");
var databaseName = databaseConfig.GetValue<string>("name");

var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var db = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);            
var collection = db.GetCollection("users");
```

This is neither creating the database or the collection. I am viewing this in the emulator's data explorer and Robo3T client.

I was under the impression that `client.GetDatabase(databaseName)` and `db.GetCollection<User>("users")` will create if the database and collection does not exist respectively.

I can get it to create the database and collection with the following `db.CreateCollection("users")`. This will require me to check if the collection first exists and isn't the prescribed approach.

Does anyone have any insights into this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: If this worked for you please mark the answer as resolved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a document, the collection gets created, don't ask why!

Comment: I ended up abandoning the mongo api for azure cosmos db and going with sql api.